# Python 3.6, Wine and asyncio - ImportError: cannot import name '_overlapped'

Tags: python, wine

I'm trying to install Flask inside Wine so that I can package with cx_freeze. I've had it working for a while, but I've just added Flask to the project.

However, I can't seem to import Flask due to a missing library required by the core asyncio library. The cause of this is an import that is only included in windows systems called `_overlapped`. The code can be [seen here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/asyncio/__init__.py#L13).

I can confirm that there is a library contained within the dlls folder:

```
root@375a857194f3:/src# find /root/.wine -iname *overlapped*
/root/.wine/drive_c/Python36/DLLs/_overlapped.pyd
```

An example import and error message can be found below.

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import asyncio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import _overlapped
ImportError: cannot import name '_overlapped'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import _overlapped  # Will also be exported.
OSError: [WinError 10045] Windows Error 0x273d
```

Comment: Looks like 32bit libraries are the problem. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077745/python-asyncio-overlapped-is-not-imported)