# Python asyncio '_overlapped' is not imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-asyncio

Could not import **asyncio** library in virtualenv.

- Python 3.6.4 x32
- Win 10 x64

> ```
> Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>>import asyncio
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python36\Lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
>     from . import _overlapped
> ImportError: cannot import name '_overlapped'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\Python36\Lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
>     import _overlapped  # Will also be exported.
> OSError: [WinError 0] The operation completed successfully
> ```

There is no module **_overlapped** in asyncio folder "C:\Python36\Lib\asyncio\". Also I know that asyncio is a part of Python from version 3.4.

What is wrong and what should i do? Could it be due to x64 Win and not x64 Python?

Comment: My guess is that your virtualenv created using Python with different bitness then currently installed in your system. Try to recreate virtualenv using currently installed Python and see if asyncio will work.

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov, thank you very much, the solution for me was in removing of the python 3.6.4 x32, removing of the virtual environment and recreating it with new python 3.6.4 x64

Comment: It got resolved by recreating virtual environment

Comment: I removed virtualenv and install all library and virtual env but that did not work