# Cannot start Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda Prompt (error: async)

Tags: python, initialization, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, startup

For the past three months since the initial installation, I've been opening jupyter notebook by going into Anaconda Prompt and simply typing "jupyter notebook"; however, starting from this afternoon I've been getting the error message below. Starting jupyter notebook in my windows start menu doesn't work either, and I can't get Anaconda Navigator to start either. I've also tried uninstalling and re-installing all Anaconda and Python related programs, but it still shows the same error message below

```
(base) C:\Users\jieming>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jieming\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import _overlapped
ImportError: cannot import name '_overlapped'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jieming\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\jieming\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 38, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  File "C:\Users\jieming\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    _patch_async()
  File "C:\Users\jieming\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 78, in _patch_async
    from jinja2.asyncsupport import patch_all
  File "C:\Users\jieming\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 13, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Users\jieming\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import _overlapped  # Will also be exported.
OSError: [WinError 10107] 系统调用失败 (roughly translates into: failure to call the relevant system)。
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077745/python-asyncio-overlapped-is-not-imported could be related

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Hi Jacques, thanks for pointing me to that thread; unfortunately, I'm not a very advanced programmer, and I don't understand what the OP meant by "removing of the python 3.6.4 x32, removing of the virtual environment and recreating it with new python 3.6.4 x64"

Would you mind explaining how to remove the virtual env and recreating it with python 3.6.4 x64?

Comment: In the link I pointed to, a 32bits version of Python is installed on a 64 bits windows 10. The issue was solved by changing python to the 32 bits version. Which anaconda did you install? 32 or 64 bits? Is your windows platform 64 bits?